# Why is col-xs-0 taking 100% of the row width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

My Bootstrap container looks like this:

```
<main >

<div class="row co-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="background-color:red; height: 100vh;"></div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-xs-0" style="background-color:blue; height: 100vh;">

  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-0 col-xs-0" style="background-color:green; height: 100vh;">      </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-10" style="background-color:yellow; height: 100vh;">

  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-1 col-xs-1" style="background-color:gray; height: 100vh;"></div>
</div>

</main>
```

When checking it in developer Tools it shows up that the blue container takes 100 of the screen (instead of being 0px) and the red one is below..any ideas why?

Thank you!

Comment: First of all does the col-xs-0 class actually exist?

Comment: col-xs-0 is nothing and if you want to hide on xs use .d-xs-none

Comment: Thank you! But here it says that col-xs should also work? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/

Comment: You have to add a number between 1 and 12 (assuming you work with a 12 column grid) after the "col-xs" in bootstrap 3 for it to work properly. If you want to hide something you have to use hidden- or visible- classes

Comment: Everything is clear now, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

col-xs-0 doesn't exist, if you want to remove it

> As such, the classes are named using the format:
>
> .d-{value} for xs .d-{breakpoint}-{value} for sm, md, lg, and xl.
>   Where value is one of:
>
> none inline inline-block block table table-cell table-row flex
>   inline-flex